# How to create a more concise table with these 2 variables? (R programming)

Tags: r

I am using the dataset nba_ht_wt which can be imported via text(readr) by the url [http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/nba_ht_wt.csv](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/data/nba_ht_wt.csv) . The question I am trying to tackle is "What percentage of players have a BMI over 25, which is considered "overweight"?

I already created a new variable in the table called highbmi, which corresponds to bmi > 25. This is my code, but the table is hard to read, how could I get a more concise and easier to read table?

```
nba_ht_wt = nba_ht_wt %>% mutate(highbmi = bmi>25)
tab = table(nba_ht_wt$highbmi, nba_ht_wt$Player)
100*prop.table(tab,1)
```

I am using R programming.

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable called bmi in the data provided so I will take a guess it is calculated via formula **Weight/Height^2**, where height is in meters.

```
data <- read.csv("http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/nba_ht_wt.csv")
head(data)
          Player Pos Height Weight Age
1  Nate Robinson   G     69    180  29
2  Isaiah Thomas   G     69    185  24
3   Phil Pressey   G     71    175  22
4   Shane Larkin   G     71    176  20
5      Ty Lawson   G     71    195  25
6 John Lucas III   G     71    157  30
```

I am no expert but it looks to me like height and weight have it names swapped for some reason.
So I will make this adjustment to calculate bmi:

```
data$bmi <- data$Height/(data$Weight/100)**2
```

And now we can answer  "What percentage of players have a BMI over 25, which is considered "overweight"? with simple line of code:

```
mean(data$bmi > 25)
```

Multiply this number by 100 to get answer in percentages. So the answer will be 1.782178%

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the formula: weight (lb) / [height (in)]^2 * 703 (source: https://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/adult_bmi/index.html), you could do:

```r
library(data.table)
nba_ht_wt <- fread("http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/data/nba_ht_wt.csv")
nba_ht_wt[, highbmi:=(Weight / Height**2 * 703)>25][,
  .(`% of Players`=round(.N/dim(nba_ht_wt)[1]*100,2)), by="highbmi"][]
#>    highbmi % of Players
#> 1:    TRUE        45.35
#> 2:   FALSE        54.65
```

... or plug in the formula into the previous response for a base R solution.

This simple formula might not be really appropriate for basketball players, obviously.